# Codeigniter access session in hooks pre_controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

When i loaded session library only show 
**Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php**
and here is code

```
$ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->load->database();
        $ci->load->library('session');
        if($ci->session->userdata('loggedin')){
            if($ci->session->userdata('owner_id')==0){
                $query = $ci->db->query("SELECT * FROM system WHERE user_id=".$ci->session->userdata('id')." LIMIT 1");
            }else{
                $query = $ci->db->query("SELECT * FROM system WHERE user_id=".$ci->session->userdata('owner_id')." LIMIT 1");
            }
        }else{
            $query = $ci->db->query("SELECT * FROM system WHERE id=1 LIMIT 1");
        }
```

Comment: If 'Session.php' is a library, why are you trying to load it like this? Why don't you load by the default framework  loading methods?

Comment: I can not find access to Session. do you have any code access Session without load method?

Comment: Yep. In fact, You should load the session lib in the 'config/autoload.php', and invoke '$ci->session->userdata('item_name')' normally, once a hook it is a part of CI as well. Remember: as a part of the framework (not the application), a HOOK expects to get all things already loaded,  and is not a correct place to load libs.

Comment: @ShutUpMagda  i agreed with you but auto load also not working. so can you tell me how to use session items before loading any functions . actually i need check user logged and if logged get some information from the database then set the config to application. do you know any other way?

Comment: There is no other way. I don't know why you need this in `pre_controller`, but keep in mind that some features are not fully loaded at this time. Consider switching to `post_controller_constructor`, which seems more appropriate for what you want.

Comment: Just i want to check the user is logged before load any function. just like index.php in PHP. anyway you tried to help me and i will give that operation. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use construct function to load the session

```
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');

}
```

or load the session library in application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Hope it will help

Comment: no, my friend, it's not possible when i loaded in autoload also show 'Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php'

Comment: Can you show your extended Class @SasinduJayampathi

Comment: <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Myapp extends CI_Controller
{
    public function appset()
    {

Comment: using controller CI_Controller

Comment: can you change to MX_Controller and check ?

Comment: Type: Error

Message: Class 'MX_Controller' not found

Comment: use this $this->ci->load->library('Session');@SasinduJayampathi

Comment: Same think Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php